# Add event listener after a table loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener, jquery-events

**Small-context**:
I am working with django templates. There is a table that is generic in structure and thus is being used at more than once place. Now, there is a button in the table to print a PDF document. I have a web page where that table is loaded in two different places with a small difference. At one place it is loaded directly by calling the include tag. But, on the other place, it is being loaded via Ajax. Now, one may ask why two different ways to which I can only answer: nature of the workflow of that component (legacy s/w).

**Issue**:
Coming to the main point. I have created a Javascript file that takes care of handling the print related workflow. Initially that Javascript file had an `eventlistener` attached to the button which is set to activate when it is clicked.

```
jQuery().ready(() => {
    jQuery('.dna-sample-material-page-button').on('click', printDnaSampleLabelMaterialPageHandler)
})
```

But, due to the differences in the way the table is being loaded, the event listener works only for the table being loaded directly but not on the one loaded via Ajax.
To overcome that issue, I tried the following:

```
jQuery().ready(() => {
    jQuery('.samples-table-unit-part').on('load', () => {
        jQuery('.dna-sample-material-page-button').on('click', printDnaSampleLabelMaterialPageHandler)
    })
})
```

where **'.samples-table-unit-part'** is the class associated to the table loaded via Ajax.
But, it does not work. My main motto is to add event listeners to all the buttons belonging to the table. Is it the correct way to add an event listener. If not what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases of content added after `DOM ready` event use event delegation.
Try something like this:

```
jQuery('.samples-table-unit-part')
.on('click', '.dna-sample-material-page-button', printDnaSampleLabelMaterialPageHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I got another idea from the answer you suggested and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help @AishwaryShukla!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `<iframe/>`, `<object/>` and `<img/>` elements, `<table>` or any other static HTMLElement do not have load events, so you load event on `.samples-table-unit-part` will never fire.

You should locate the part of the code where the table is loaded with AJAX and attach your event listener only after inserting the table in the DOM.

Comment: This is a very great advice. Thank you.